# insert if exist on another table mysql on a specific value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

Table1 has 2 columns, `id` and `city` with 4 rows (names of city).

| id | city |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | surabaya |
| 2 | jakarta |
| 3 | bandung |

Table2 has 4 columns, `id`, `city`, `produk` and `price`.

| id | city | produk | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | depok | apel | 1500 |
| 2 | pekanbaru | jeruk | 2000 |
| 3 | Nasional | mangga | 2200 |

I have 1 record on table2 that has value "Nasional" on column city

How can I update this 1 row and insert the names of the city on table1

expected result

| id | city | produk | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | depok | apel | 1500 |
| 2 | pekanbaru | jeruk | 2000 |
| 3 | surabaya | mangga | 2200 |
| 4 | jakarta | mangga | 2200 |
| 5 | bandung | mangga | 2200 |

How can I achieve this

```
INSERT INTO table2
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE name='nasional'
);
```

Comment: Please do not add text as a picture. Please copy and paste your text into the question formatting it appropriate as a table or as code with the editor and markup language of stackoverflow.

Comment: Please post data example and expected results

Comment: What is the relation between the tables? How come `jakarta, bandung, semarang` get `sugar=700`? Currently, it don't make sense. How about you do this, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE Table1` and on `Table2`, then post the result [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71212310/edit).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
 UPDATE table2
 SET name="nasional"
 WHERE table2.name = table1.name;
```

Comment: i have updated my question. i hope i make sense